# Generate Javadoc HTML using maven?

Tags: maven-3, maven-javadoc-plugin

Right now I am using the maven-javadoc-plugin to attach the Javadoc to .jar artifacts when I am doing a release.

However, how can I generate the Javadoc in an html format so we can scp it to a remote server for reference?

Thanks!

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Using the same plugin, you can generate javadoc in a folder using

```
mvn javadoc:javadoc
```

It puts the help content under `target/site/apidocs`

You can change the output folder by using the plugin configuration parameter `reportOutputDirectory`

Please refer to:

- [Apache Maven Javadoc Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/)

Comment: What if I want to generate the javadocs when i execute `clean install` command. I am currently trying that, but the java docs are not getting generated on Clean install. I am using `<id>javadoc:javadoc</id> <phase>package</phase>`

Answer (score 15):

if you are interested in just doing it raw, you could use the following command.

```
javadoc -d C:/javadoc/test com.mypackage
```

Comment: you are right, somethings are so easy and maven make us believe that everything is so complex tha twe need maven in situations that are quite trivial!

Comment: y'all need to use ant for a a half-complex build process, then tell me maven's vile.  maven is a life-saver and i, for one, welcome my xml-based overlords