# Intellij Idea JavaDoc with Java and Kotlin mixed code

Tags: java, kotlin, intellij-idea, javadoc

enter image description hereI have a Spring Boot project that has been written partially in Java and partially in Kotlin using IntelliJ IDEA. The problem is that when I try to generate JavaDoc, I get errors for the Kotlin packages import directives that are declared inside the Java class files:

```
error: package xxxx.yyyyyy.zzzzz does not exist
```

But that's wrong, because the project is successfully built and run. Has anyone an idea on how to fix that ?

See pictures:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you use `Tools | Generate JavaDoc` action in the IDE for generation? If yes please provide a screenshot of this dialog before clicking on `Generate`. Also, provide the real out without masking package names (if possible).

Comment: I have done what you asked @EgorKlepikov

Comment: Does it work if you generate javadoc using Maven goal https://stackoverflow.com/a/9971275/12844632 ? Please check if it works from the command line outside of IntelliJ IDEA.